# Find the difference between two times in java

Tags: java, date, grails, time, date-arithmetic

I have a search button, when the user clicks the search button the search() method is get called. I need to calculate the how much time it took to display the result to the user as we see in the google search.

This is my code.

```
        SimpleDateFormat sdfDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
String strDate;
def startTime() { 
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    System.out.println("Current milliseconds since 13 Oct, 2008 are :"
    + cal.getTimeInMillis());
    long startTime=cal.getTimeInMillis();
    /*Date startNow = new Date();
    strDate = sdfDate.format(startNow);
    Date startTime=sdfDate.parse(strDate);
    print "startTime"+startTime*/
    return  startTime;

}
def endTime(){
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    System.out.println("Current milliseconds  :"
    + cal.getTimeInMillis());
    long endTime=cal.getTimeInMillis();
    /*Date endNow = new Date();
    print "endNow"+endNow
    strDate = sdfDate.format(endNow);
    Date endTime=sdfDate.parse(strDate);
    print "endTime"+endTime*/
    return endTime;
}

def differenceTime(long startTime,long endTime){
    print "requestEndTime"+endTime
    print "requestStartTime"+startTime
    long timeDifference = endTime - startTime;
    return timeDifference;
}
```

Here I am trying to get the starttime and endtime and trying to calculate the difference. I do know whether the way I implemented is right? Please tell me usually how the time difference is being calculated.

Comment: Didn't I see you with a very similar question 15 minutes ago?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of using `Calendar` it's easier to use `System.currentTimeMillis()`:

```
def startTime() { 
    long startTime=System.currentTimeMillis();
    return  startTime;
}
```

Calculating time difference based on System.currentTimeMillis() is very common in Java, and you'll doing it right (I mean `endTime - startTime`)

So, your code could looks like:

```
long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
// .....
// processing request
// .....
long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
long differenceTime = endTime - startTime;
log.debug("Request time: " + differenceTime);
//or
log.debug("Request time: " + TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(differenceTime) + " sec");
```

Comment: How to check the difference between the starttime and endtime return in milliseconds is correct?

Comment: If you want in seconds, then:

long differenceTimeInSecs = (endTime - startTime)/1000;

Comment: or `TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(endTime - startTime)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use this class instead. I learnt it while pursuing Coursera's Algorithms, Part I class.

```
public class StopWatch {

    /* Private Instance Variables */
    /** Stores the start time when an object of the StopWatch class is initialized. */
    private long startTime;

    /**
     * Custom constructor which initializes the {@link #startTime} parameter.
     */
    public StopWatch() {
        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }

    /**
     * Gets the elapsed time (in seconds) since the time the object of StopWatch was initialized.
     * 
     * @return Elapsed time in seconds.
     */
    public double getElapsedTime() {
        long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        return (double) (endTime - startTime) / (1000);
    }
}
```

The test can be done as:

```
public class SWTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        StopWatch stopWatch = new StopWatch();

        Thread.sleep(10000);
        System.out.println(stopWatch.getElapsedTime());
        Thread.sleep(60000);
        System.out.println(stopWatch.getElapsedTime());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can code it like this:

```
LocalDateTime startTIme = LocalDateTime.now();
//Code Here
LocalDateTime endTime = LocalDateTime.now();
System.out.println(Duration.between(startTIme,endTime));
```

Comment: Incorrect answer. The `Local…` types lose any information about time zone, as that is their reason for being. That means you will get incorrect duration calculation when rolling over a change-over of Daylight Saving Time (DST) or other anomaly. For example, [in Montréal this year](http://www.timeanddate.com/time/change/canada/montreal?year=2016), if your code ran for a minute at 2016-03-13T01:59:50, the result of your code would incorrectly be one hour and a minute as the clock "sprung forward" for DST from 2 AM to 3 AM.

Comment: I just answered the question asked.
If you want to capture zonal details you can use ZonedDateTime.

Comment: But your code will fail, reporting incorrect results during anomalous moments such as DST cut-over. Say your first line captures the time `2016-03-13T01:59:50` in Montréal. The part you mark as `//Code Here` takes a full minute to run. During that minute the clock "springs forward" one hour with DST, jumping from 2 AM to 3 AM. Your 3rd line of code will capture the *local* date-time of `2016-03-13T03:01:50`, the 3 AM hour (`…T03:…`) rather than 2 AM (`…T02:…`) as seen on most other days. Your code reports a duration of 1 hour + 1 minute (PT1H1M) rather than 1 minute (PT1M).

Comment: Ok, I understood what you are complaining. You can see the underline implementation of LocalDateTime in the JDK source to find how they are handling TimeZone.
See the method Clock.systemDefaultZone()

Answer (score 0):

## java.time

Avoid the old legacy java.util.Date/.Calendar classes. After proving to be poorly designed and troublesome, the old date-time classes have been supplanted by the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework. See [Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). See new methods added to old classes for conversion.

Defined by [JSR 310](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310). Much of java.time functionality has been [back-ported to Java 6 & 7](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), and [further adapted to Android](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP).

### `Instant`

An [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) represents a moment on the timeline in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) with a resolution of up to [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond).

Capturing the current moment is limited to [milliseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Millisecond) resolution because of reliance on an old pre-existing implementation of [`Clock`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Clock.html); replaced in Java 9 to capture current moment in nanoseconds (depending on your computer’s hardware clock capability).

```
Instant start = Instant.now();
…
Instant stop = Instant.now();
```

### `Duration`

The [`Duration`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html) class represents a span of time as a total number of seconds plus a fraction of a second in nanoseconds.

```
Duration duration = Duration.between( start , stop );
```

### Output

The `Duration::toString` method generates a textual representation using the standard ISO 8601 format. Begins with a `P` (for period), and a `T` separates years-months-days from hours-minutes-seconds. So an hour and a half would be `PT1H30M`. This format avoids the ambiguity of `01:30` meaning elapsed time versus time-of-day.

```
String output = duration.toString();
```

Alternatively, you can ask for the total number of whole seconds and the total number of nanoseconds.

```
long seconds = duration.getSeconds();  // Whole seconds.
int nanoseconds = duration.getNano();  // Fraction of a second, maximum of 999,999,999.
```