# Total time spent of IP

Tags: java, string, ip

I guys, I am new to Java please help or guide me, I have this string input from file:

```
        **IP**            **Date**
(1.39.15.91 ,30/Sep/2014,18:45:17 )
(1.39.15.91 ,30/Sep/2014,18:45:24 )
(1.39.15.91 ,30/Sep/2014,18:45:26 )
(173.0.48.47 ,30/Sep/2014,18:41:48 )
(69.12.70.89 ,30/Sep/2014,18:20:07 )
(119.18.55.52 ,30/Sep/2014,18:05:30 )
(119.18.55.52 ,30/Sep/2014,18:30:58 )
(119.18.55.52 ,30/Sep/2014,18:30:59 )
```

I am trying to get total time spent of IP.

Expected output:

```
 1.39.15.91   date   total time spent of this ip(18:45:17-18:45:26)
 173.0.48.47  date   total time spent of this ip ( zero )
 69.12.70.89  date   total time spent of this ip (zero )
 119.18.55.52  date  total time spent of this ip(18:05:30-18:30:59)
```

What I tried:

```
       String sCurrentLine;

        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("D:\\test.txt"));

        while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {

            //String str=value.toString();
              String[] tokens = sCurrentLine.split(","); //split into Words
              System.out.println(sCurrentLine);
        }
```

Comment: What've you done so far? are you able to atleast get the data from file in java?

Comment: have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14494569/find-the-difference-between-two-times-in-java

Comment: Please give what output you expect from the above input data?

Comment: @user1354678 i m reading the file, and and separate out IP and Date from space and after that what should i do ?? i dont know ;(

Comment: Your edit does not show the `"total time spent"`

Comment: Where in your code do you have a problem? What error are you getting?

Comment: @aashish_soni Please review my answer and let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were on the right track when you tried splitting each line by comma, but you need a bit more work to get going.  In the code below I parse your input file line-by-line, using a `HashMap` to store the maximum and minimum `Date` objects for each IP address:

```
Map<String, Date> minMap = new HashMap<String, Date>();
Map<String, Date> maxMap = new HashMap<String, Date>();
String sCurrentLine;
br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("D:\\test.txt"));

while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
    //String str=value.toString();
    sCurrentLine = sCurrentLine.substring(1, sCurrentLine.length - 1);
    String[] tokens = sCurrentLine.split(","); //split into words
    // (173.0.48.47 ,30/Sep/2014,18:41:48 )
    String timeStamp = tokens[1] + " " tokens[2];

    try {
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MMM/yyyy hh:mm:ss");
        Date parsedDate = dateFormat.parse(timeStamp);
        if (minMap.get(tokens[0]) == null) {
            minMap.put(tokens[0], parsedDate);
            maxMap.put(tokens[0], parsedDate);
        } else if (parsedDate.compareTo(minMap.get(tokens[0]) < 0) {
            minMap.put(tokens[0], parsedDate);
        } else if (parsedDate.compareTo(minMap.get(tokens[0]) > 0) { {
            maxMap.put(tokens[0], parsedDate);
        }
    } catch(Exception e){
    }
}

// iterate over max and min Maps and print result for each IP address
Set<Map.Entry<String, Date>> entrySet = minMap.entrySet();
for (Entry entry : entrySet) {
    String message = entry.getKey() + " date total time spent of this ip (";
    if (entry.getValue().compareTo(maxMap.get(entry.getKey()) == 0) {
        message = "zero";
    else {
        message += minMap.get(entry.getKey()) + "-" + maxMap.get(entry.getKey());
    }
    message += ")";
}
```

In your example output above, you omit the date from the timestamp range, but in practice you could have different dates, so I included this in my code.  Also, if you want to get the *difference* between two timestamps in milliseconds (or another format) it would also be a bit more work.

Answer (score 0):

Split it into substrings using the commas as a delimiter.

You can then delete the commas if wanted.

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_split.htm